# deserializeStrict method: bug?

Tags: apex, json, exception, deserialize, serialization

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm) about the `deserializeStrict` method in `JSON` class is (emphasis added):

> All attributes in the JSON string must be present in the specified type. If the JSON content contains attributes not present in the System.Type argument, such as a missing field or object, deserialization fails in some circumstances. When deserializing JSON content with extraneous attributes into an Apex class, this method throws an exception in all API versions. *However, no exception is thrown when you use this method to deserialize JSON content into a custom object or an sObject.*

I wrote this code to test it:

```
String jsonString = '{"first":"value1", "second":"value2", "third":"value3"}';
Account c = (Account)JSON.deserializeStrict(jsonString, Account.class);
System.debug(c);`
```

And I receive this exception:

> Exception: System.JSONException: No such column 'first' on sobject of type Account
>   StackTrace: Class.System.JSON.deserializeStrict: line 19, column 1
>   AnonymousBlock: line 2, column 1
>   AnonymousBlock: line 2, column 1
>   LINE: 19 COLUMN: 1

Reading the documentation I understand that no exception is thrown when you use this method to deserialize JSON content into a custom object or an sObject. **Is this interpretation correct or not?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Aside from that last sentence the documentation is spot on. However, I would argue that the behavior is correct, and it is just that sentence which is flawed.

---

It is easy to demonstrate that for a `custom object`, it is flat out incorrect. What they mean is an instance of a custom defined class. Let's check:

**Script**

```
class Demo { }
Demo instance = (Demo)JSON.deserializeStrict('{"first": 1}', Demo.class);
```

**Error**

> System.JSONException: Unknown field: Demo.first

Sure does throw.

---

It's a little trickier to demonstrate with an `sObject`, however. Sure, it throws an error with a concrete `sObjectType`, but it could in theory work for a generic instance.

**Script**

```
String payload = '{"first": 1}';
SObject record = (SObject)JSON.deserializeStrict(payload, SObject.class);
```

**Error**

> System.JSONException: Nested object for polymorphic foreign key must have an attributes field before any other fields.

Okay...let's try adding that attribute:

**Script**

```
String payload = '{"attributes": {}, "first": 1}';
SObject record = (SObject)JSON.deserializeStrict(payload, SObject.class);
```

**Error**

> System.JSONException:

Hmm...not that helpful. Let's try specifying a valid `attributes` value.

**Script**

```
String payload = '{"attributes":{"type":"Account"}, "first": 1}';
SObject record = (SObject)JSON.deserializeStrict(payload, SObject.class);
```

**Error**

> System.JSONException: No such column 'first' on sobject of type Account

Back to the same error we had when it was a specific `sObjectType`.

Just to be sure, we can also try it with a custom `sObjectType`.

**Script**

```
MyObject__c record = (MyObject__c)JSON.deserializeStrict('{"first": 1}', MyObject__c.class);
```

**Error**

> System.JSONException: No such column 'first' on sobject of type MyObject__c

So it looks like the documentation is in fact incorrect in that last sentence.